# Show text after clicking a button

Tags: javascript, html, css

I got this h1 tag that I want change when clicking a button.

I want it so then when you click a button, an h1 tag will change to something else, like to "bananas" or something. How could I use an onclick event to change it?

Comment: Since no one responded I chose to do it myself. It is pretty simple.

Comment: "Simple" is often simple *after* you know how to do it. Im glad you figured it out yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ([addEventListener](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_eventlistener.asp)) with (click) event to listen on click button by using javascript code.
i hope it's clear and helpful, Thanks!.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
</head>

<body>

    <!-- My Heading -->
    <h1 id="MyHeading">This is a Heading</h1>
    <!-- My Button -->
    <button id="MyButton">Click Me!</button>

</body>

</html>

<script>
    //Select button by id
    const MyButton = document.getElementById('MyButton');
    //Add on click listener for button
    MyButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
        //Select (h1) heading by id, and then change it's value to (bananas)
        document.getElementById('MyHeading').innerText = "bananas"
    })
</script>
```